# php header with curl always got UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, authorization

I want to develop a bridging application to web service. I Tried using the encrypted TIMESTAMP, SIGNATURE, AND AUTHORIZATION code with ARC (google add on for web service) to test if my encryption codes are correct and it worked. In my php script All requirements (parameters) are already provided but I always get Unauthorized access even though the password and username are correct. Please help. i'm using php curl. Thank for your help.

this is my php script :

```
<?php

$data = "xxx";               
$secretKey = "xxx";                  
$url = "http://someurl";              
$nik = "xxx";

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');                
$tStamp = strval(time()-strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00'));           
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $data."&".$tStamp, $secretKey, true); 
$encodedSignature = base64_encode($signature);            
$urlencodedSignature = urlencode($encodedSignature); 

$pcareUname = "zzz";        
$pcarePWD   = "zzz";        
$kdAplikasi = "zzz";        
$encodedAuthorization = base64_encode($pcareUname.":".$pcarePWD.":".$kdAplikasi);              

    //showing result from encode                  
echo "X-cons-id: " .$data;   
echo "X-timestamp:" .$tStamp;                  
echo "X-signature: " .$encodedSignature;                   
echo "X-authorization: " .$encodedAuthorization";                

$ch = curl_init();                    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url.$nik);              
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "X-cons-id: $data",
    "X-timestamp: $tStamp",
    "X-signature: $signature",
    "X-authorization: Basic $encodedAuthorization"
    ));

$result = curl_exec($ch);               
curl_close($ch);        
echo($result); 
?>
```

Comment: i think your `$encodedAuthorization` is wrongly encoded. otherwise, the encoding scheme was created by a retard. if that is really the correct scheme, what do you think happens if someone has `:` in their username/password?

Comment: thanks for responding. you're right about what if someone uses     : as his/her user/pass. let's say luckily no one has ever used    :, is there any mistake in my php script? or why is it, when i was using ARC (google add on), i got success result?

Comment: idk, but you say `it works`, record what ARC is doing then, should be able to deduce what you're doing wrong with a recording of a successfull auth (can highly recommend [Fiddler Proxy](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) - it even has fake certificate generation and https ssl/tls MITM attack capabilities that works flawlessly to even spy on https sessions - and it's free)